# Checkboxes not working with markdown in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, markdown

I have the following code for checkboxes,

```
### Pre-requisites

- [ ] You should have done the Verilog parsign of all the files (../parse_verilog/)
- [ ] You should have generated CDFGs for all the modules (../gen_cdfg/)
```

which appears in Bitbucket like the following (with bullets instead of checkboxes) [image: bullets]

What could be the reason?

**Update (2-Jul-2020)**
If Bitbucket enables this feature, please post a comment below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checkboxes are a non-standard Markdown feature, which are not supported by most Markdown implementations. Bitbucket documents their Markdown implementation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html).

> Bitbucket Server uses Markdown for formatting text, as specified in [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) (with a few extensions).

Note that Commonmark does not include support for checkboxes, and they are not listed among the extensions in Bitbucket's documentation. Therefore, it should be safe to assume that they are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

One can add checkboxes by converting comments into tasks (Create Task button).

Example follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old issue, but it came up when I searched for the same thing. Bitbucket supports "tasks" being added to comments. What you do is create the comment first, then use the "Create task" option on the comment to add a checkbox. It has the added benefit of being a soft-block for the PR. You have to check the box before it will let you merge.

More info here: https://bitbucket.org/blog/introducing-pull-request-tasks